# 6502 indirect addressing issues

Tags: assembly, 6502, commodore

i'm having some trouble with the following code for a 6502 machine:

```
C000 LDA #$00
C002 STA $FE
C004 LDA #$20
C006 STA $FF
C008 LDY #$08
C00A LDX #$00
C00C DEY
C00D CPY #$FF
C00F BEQ $C01B
C011 LDA ($FE),Y
C013 CMP #$2F
C015 BPL $C00C
C017 INX
C018 JMP $C00C
C01B BRK
```

The exercise is to store the numbers 2, 1 and 4 starting from the address 2000 and say what are the values of A, X and Y.

I'm "running" my code with pen and paper but I got stuck at C011 for the following reason:
`LDA ($FE),Y` 
It loads in A the value stored at the memory address calculated this way:

1. pick `$FE` value (that at first is 00)
2. Add the value of Y (that at first iteration is 7)
3. I now have 07
4. Load A with the value stored at 07

Is this correct? Am I missing something?
If I'm not, where do I use the values stored in `2000` `2001` and `2002` ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you're not correct. You're missing the meaning of `LDA ($FE),Y` which uses the [indirect indexed](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly#Zero_Page_Indirect_Indexed_with_Y:_.28zp.29.2Cy) (as opposed to indexed indirect) addressing mode. Indirect means the value inside the parentheses is the address of a 16-bit pointer, low byte first. That's the $00 and $20 you set up earlier, so $2000.

The indexing is done with Y, and your loop exit condition is based on Y, so you have that. The value of A is the last value read, so you have that too.

But your comment & question on Weather Vane's answer is very relevant. The values in the other memory locations matter because of the `CMP #$2F` and subsequent `BPL` and `INX`. CMP acts like a subtract, and the N flag is set if the compared register < compared memory; [see here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly#Compare_and_Test_Bit).

So the value of X depends on those other memory values.

Comment: Yeah I know that. The fact is that i'm asked to "load the least significant bytes of my badge number (intepreted as hexadecimal value) starting from `$2000`. My number is 0648214, so I will load `14` in `$2000`, `82` in `$2001` and `64` in `$2002`. (Yeah I realized my values in the question are wrong, but nothing changes). Doing so, I've no idea of the values from `$2003` to `$2007`. I dumped memory in my virtual machine many times, values unset are all zero, always. I'm feeling very stupid

Comment: No stupidity required. ; - ) Assembly is very fiddly till you get the hang of it. Anyway, if you're using a virtual machine then hopefully it documents the initial memory state. In any case, it sounds like memory is preset to zero (though that isn't necessarily the case with a real machine). Any location value > #$2F will trigger the INX in your code.

Comment: so can i assume that is zero safely?

Comment: I take it this is an assignment? If the VM documentation, question etc doesn't specify then you'll have to make an assumption. It looks safe based on your testing.

Comment: Yeah it is an old test, I'm studying for my test. In class we used the VICE emulator. I can't find any specification on the documentation (maybe I'm not looking in the right place). By the way, I'm having class tomorrow with the professor, asking won't hurt me! Until tomorrow I'll hold to that assumption. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: VICE emulates various Commodore systems, which I hardly used, but it has [options to initialize memory](http://vice-emu.sourceforge.net/vice_6.html#SEC87) with various patterns presumably like those found on other real systems of the time. The Apple II had repeats of 00's and FF's and occasional random values. Anyway, zero is a safe bet for an assignment. ; - ) Have fun and good luck.

Comment: @magicleon With respect to the numbers loaded at `$2000` I believe it is expecting the ASCII characters for your badge number. ie `30 36 34 38 32 31 34` This is because the `CMP $2F / BPL` is essentially asking "is this byte `$30` or greater?"

Answer (score 5):

> pick $FE value (that at first is 00)

Actually, it loads a 16-bit value from `$FE`, and then adds `Y` to that value to get the effective address.

You've stored `$00` at `$FE` and `$20` at `$FF`, so the 16-bit value loaded from `$FE` will be `$2000`

> where do I use the values stored in 2000 2001 and 2002

When `Y` has the value 0, 1, and 2. The loop will continue until `Y` wraps around from 0 to $FF.

---

See *"10) Post-indexed indirect"* in [6502.txt](http://nesdev.com/6502.txt).

Comment: It's easy to remember the post-indirect because of the parentheses: `lda ($00,x)` loads from the memory address at `$00 + x`, but `lda ($00),y` loads from (the memory address in 0) + y.  `lda ($00,x)` adds X *before* dereferencing, but `lda ($00),y` adds Y *after* dereferencing.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the value at `$2007` (first iteration) is zero?

Answer (score 2):

This addressing mode is called *post-indexed indirect* and is used only with the `Y` register. The effective address is formed from the (little-endian) contents of address `$00FE` and `$00FF` and `Y` is added to that address.

You stored `$2000` in those two page zero locations, and `Y` holds `7` so the effective address is `$2007`, beyond the three bytes of data you wish to access.

Note that could have accessed the array directly as

```
LDA $2000,Y
```

but the advantage of the indirect method is that you don't need to know the address in advance, for example you could select one of several tables to be indexed depending on run-time conditions.

Comment: Well, then A is loaded with the content of `$2007` at first. The thing is, I've never loaded anything in `$2007`... Is it  safe to consider that content zero? I don't think so..

Comment: In a higher level language that would be called "undefined behaviour". If you have not set the contents at address `$2007` (either directly in code or because it is a predefined location in `ROM`) then you can assume nothing about its content. On power up the contents of volatile `RAM` *might* be set to a regular pattern, but that's just a quirk of the hardware. If you are using a virtual machine as commented above, perhaps the `RAM` is all initialised to `0` by the host but it is not something you should rely on.